# How to display an image $_FILE on PHP

Tags: php

I have a code here that handles the upload of the images.

However for some reason the $file_destination variable is unrecognize outsizde the ifs statements. Basically what I want to attain is output the $file_destination variable inside a  tag. however when i use the variable it wont just work outside.

```
//FILE UPLOADING CODES (NEED TO BE INSIDE A FUNCTION)
     global $file_destination;
     if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        print_r($file);
        // File properties
        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        //File Extension 
        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        //Check which file type allowed
        $allowed = array('png', 'jpg');

        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
            if($file_error === 0){
                if($file_size <= 2097152){
                    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true). '.'.$file_ext;
                    $file_destination = 'C:/'.$file_name_new;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                        echo $file_destination;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

echo <img src="<?php $file_destination ?>">
```

it wont work since the $file_destination doesnt recognize. Any idea?

Comment: `echo <img src="<?php $file_destination ?>">` is invalid syntax. should be `echo '<img src="'.$file_destination.'">';` or `echo "<img src=\"$file_destination\">";` or ...

Comment: It wont output that outside the if. I tried to tweak but for some reason it wont just appear.

Comment: that simply cant be true, the 'if' has noting to do with it

Comment: are these `if` blocks inside a function? seeing `//FILE UPLOADING CODES (NEED TO BE INSIDE A FUNCTION)` and `global $file_destination;` makes me question.

Comment: @sean wins. OP code missing vital start of function line

Comment: @Sean: Nope it is not yet a global $file_destination. Care to help and figure it out?

Comment: can't help since I still don't understand your issue. If you define `$file_destination = 'C:/'.$file_name_new;` inside `if` blocks, then you could access `$file_destination` after the `if` blocks (as long as the `if`s were true and `$file_destination` is defined). The only way `$file_destination` is not accessible is if it was never defined, or defined inside a function and is out of scope.

Comment: yeah. I was trying to think about it too. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the security of the browser. Some browser dont let you show localfiles from your HD: c:/myimages.jpg

Try to point your "src" to a resource (image file) in your web server:

Example:
`<img src="http://localhost/myimages.jpg">`